# java change a String that contains {n} by regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String that contains expressions like these {0}, {1} ... {n}. And i have String List with n length. {0} replace with param[0], {1} replace with param[1], {n} replace with param[n]. How can I do that?

```
List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>;
param[0] = "dortmund";
param[1] = "5555";
String message = "customers address is  {0}, phone number is {1}, please check them.";
```

Comment: If you want, you could look up the implementation details of [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), which seem to do just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

```
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat("customers address is  {0}, phone number is {1}, please check them.");
Object[] args = {"dortmund", "5555"};
String message = messageFormat.format(args);
```

Comment: +1 Yes, use this class instead of **abusing regexps for trivial string substitution**.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i=0; i < params.size(); ++i) {
    message = message.replace("{"+i+"}", params[i]);
}
```

Comment: `MessageFormat` is Java 1.4, that should qualify as "plain old java", too.

Comment: You probably want to use `replace()` and not `replaceAll()`, so you can drop the regex stuff.

Comment: @BernhardBarker No. Tested and does exactly what I expect.